# How are these different? TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Can someone explain me how's this statement:

```
return [grade if (grade < 38 or grade % 5 < 3) else (grade + (5 - grade%5)) for grade in grades]
```

different from this block of code:

```
for grade in grades:
        if grade<38 or grade%5<3:
            return grade
        else:
            return grade + (5-grade%5)
```

the first one works, but the second code gives me a TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Well for starters, tehy do two completely different things. The first returns *a list* object, created by your list comprehension. The second *returns either `grade` or `grade + (5-grade%5)`*. This always happens on the first iteration, making your for-loop sort of pointless

Comment: Presumably, the error comes from trying to iterate over the result of calling the function these snippets come from?

Comment: Next time please post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Answer (score 1):

For them to output the same you would need to append your result to a list instead of returning it.
Basically the second block of code should be:

```
def block2(grades):
    res = []
    for grade in grades:
            if grade<38 or grade%5<3:
                res.append(grade)
            else:
                res.append(grade + (5-grade%5))
    return res
```